# Microsoft Adal Dont get Bearer Token

Tags: java, android, azure, adal

I am trying to get a Bearer Access token from ADAL . My Application is registered at Adal. The main problem is that I get an Token from the Server. But the Token Type which should be Bearer is NULL. How i understood is the REDIRECT URI a random URL. I think that I made a everything right. If I make the same thing with JAVA and C# I get a Bearer Token , but with android i get a token without Bearer Tokentype

```
static final String LOG_TAG = "AUTH";
String idToken;
String accessToken;
String TYPE;
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
            ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    this.Login();

}


public void Login() {


    // Create the authentication context.


    authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(MainActivity.this,
            AUTHORITY, true);





    // Acquire tokens using necessary UI.
   authenticationContext.acquireToken(MainActivity.this, GRAPH_RESOURCE, CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI,
            PromptBehavior.Always, new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {

                    accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
                    TYPE = result.getAccessTokenType();
                    // Print tokens.
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "ID Token: " + idToken);
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Access Token: " + accessToken);
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Access Type: " + result.getAccessTokenType());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception exc) {
                    // TODO: Handle error
                }
            });

}

public void click(View V) {


    new getData().execute(accessToken);

}

public void onLoginClick(View V) {

    this.Login();


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the authentication context.
    if (authenticationContext != null) {
        authenticationContext.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your values like in `AUTHORITY` etc.?

Comment: Your token is most likely a bearer token and ADAL may just be failing to say this in the getAccessTokenType() method. Try capturing the token with a breakpoint and drop it into https://jwt.ms.  Then you can inspect the token to see if it looks correct and will work in a bearer request.